# Overriding MaxZoom on Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, zoom

I cannot zoom past maxZoom: 24 - and entering a number greater than 24 is not allowed.

```
Map.setLocked(0, 1, 24);
```

Any workarounds? I have assets with ~2cm Ground-sampling Distance / Pixel size and can't see all the detail as is in Earth Engine.

Comment: I don't think it's possible unfortunately, try QGIS instead